# Angular JS Filtering numbers

Tags: angularjs

I have a filter like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in CategoryList | filter: {CategoryOption.CategoryOptionID: FilterByType}">
```

The value: FilterByType gets set from a dropdown list not shown.

This works just fine, except if the FilterByType value is a 2, for example, then it will filter the results to show 2, 22, 32, 42, etc.  It's not a true number compare.  It's more like a string.contains kinda thing.

Any idea how I can lock this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function with filter like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in CategoryList | filter: myCustomFilter">
```

And then define a function that does whatever comparison you want :

```
$scope.myCustomFilter = function(element) {
    if ($scope.FilterByType) {
        return element.number === parseInt($scope.FilterByType);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This provides total control over the filter and will also help prevent some weird behaviour with input types (text, number, etc.) not matching the actual type in the model.

Answer (score 3):

Add `true` as a third parameter to the filter expression to enable strict comparison:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in CategoryList | filter: {CategoryOption.CategoryOptionID: FilterByType}:true">
```

<sub>Note: This requires AngularJS v1.1.3+</sub>

Comment: I tried this method before but continued to get the same weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `:true` working for me.

```
ng-repeat="proj in projectList | filter: {ID: project.p_id} :true"
```

Thanks